# Objective C - Can't change value in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can retrieve data I need from API, but then I can't change values of NSMutableArray.
Here's the data I get from API:

```
{
favorites =     (
            {
        id = 766;
        imageUrl = "766.jpg";
        name = "Ground Beef 93% Lean 1LB PKG";
        price = "5.99";
        qty = 5;
        sale = "<null>";
        switch = 1;
    },
            {
        id = 3270;
        imageUrl = "3270.jpg";
        name = "Arnold Premium Italian Bread 20oz PKG";
        price = "5.39";
        qty = 5;
        sale = "<null>";
        switch = 1;
    },...
);
success = true;
}
```

I declare favorites property in the interface part :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *favorites;
```

I store the data in NSMutableArray like this :

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSMutableArray *response = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError] mutableCopy];
```

Then I store favorite products in another NSMutableArray object :

```
NSString *success = [response valueForKey:@"success"];
if([success isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
    self.favorites = [response valueForKey:@"favorites"];
}
```

With this data I can display all images, prices, etc. in the table.
Problem is when I want to update values in self.favorites mutable array:

```
[self.favorites[indexPath.row] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"switch"];
```

I get this error : -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: **mutating method sent to immutable object**.
I even tried to add mutableCopy when assigning array to favorites :

```
self.favorites = [[response valueForKey:@"favorites"] mutableCopy];
```

but that did not work either.

Comment: Your array is mutable, but the dictionaries it contains are still immutable.

Comment: Like @rmaddy said. I need NSJSONReadingMutableContainers, that's what makes the dictionaries mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`, not `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves`.

Using `NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves` gives you mutable strings and other mutable objects inside the containers. Not what you need here.